# ClickOnce with .NET 4.7.1 fails, cannot find Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical in the GAC

Tags: clickonce, .net-4.7.1

I've successfully built and deployed a ClickOnce app based on .NET 4.7.1 using the latest (stable) Visual Studio 2017 version. However, another app won't install:

[image: System Update Required error Dialog]

I've tried to install it into the GAC:

1. Find `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical` (there is a NuGet package for it, so I can find and extract the DLL)
2. Install it in the gac with `gacutil -i`.

However, I get an error message, telling me:

> Failure adding assembly to the cache:   This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Where can I find a `gacutil` which would work with the 2.0.0 version of this assembly?

Or am I doing it in the wrong way? Is there another solution to this issue?

*Edited 2017.11.18:*

I opened an issue in the [Visual Studio Developer Comunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/152706/clickonce-installation-fails-with-net-471.html).

Comment: It is just standard .NET Standard misery.  Where does that [here] link take you?  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to report bugs.

Comment: Hi Hans, the link is the one I provided when configuring my ClickOnce manifest. So it does not help me in that case.